# Cast value from Dictionary to String in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I got below error. I can print the value with print but can't declare it to label. I guess I have a problem on casting any to string.

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1b6ffd7f0) to
>   'NSString' (0x1b7009398)."

```
let dataDict: [AnyHashable: Any] = LBValueConverter.manageValueSnore(dataValue)
       // print("kUUIDSnoreSensor dict: \(dataDict)")
        let allValues = Array(dataDict.values)
        for value in allValues{
            mTextLabel.text = value as! String
        }
```

Comment: Your dictionary contains objects other than strings; in this case it is an NSNumber, somyiu force downcast will fail.

Comment: Btw, only last element of array would be showed as `mTextLabel.text`. You may save a lot of time, by just taking `allValues.last` instead of looping over.

Comment: Actually, I was printing values live to textfield. So not just one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to cast from NSNumber to String. If you have different values inside this dictionary use this:

```
for value in dataDict.values {
    if let value = value as? String {
      mTextLabel.text = value
    }
    else if let value = value as? NSNumber {
      mTextLabel.text = value.stringValue
    }
    ....
}
```

In case all values are NSNumber you can cast your dataDict to [String: NSNumber] to avoid the if-lets